# How would I get data from my url?

Tags: php

I'm pretty much a beginner.

How would I get the data from a url?,like if the url is `https://www.example.com/idk`, how would I get `idk` and whatever else was put there?

Thanks,
chexyalani.

Comment: *"I'm pretty much a beginner."* - So was I once.

Comment: We are always glad to help and support new coders but ***you need to help yourself first. :-)*** After [**doing more research**](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/261592/1011527) if you have a problem **post what you've tried** with a **clear explanation of what isn't working** and provide [a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Read [How to Ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) a good question. Be sure to [take the tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) and read [this](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/347937/1011527).

Comment: You can use `parse_url()` to parse a URL into components, you can use `basename()` to get the filename part of a pathname.

Comment: if its after ?= then the `$_GET` array, otherwise have a look at the `$_SERVER` array

Comment: parse_url($url, PHP_URL_PATH);

Ref: http://php.net/manual/en/function.parse-url.php

Comment: Thanks a lot guys. :)